# EF 6 Mapping Complex Composite Keys

Tags: frameworks, entity-framework-6, key, entity, composite

I have the following models

```
public class Company
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Journal> Journals { get; set; }

}

public class Account
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int GLAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
}

public class Journal
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

How would I map the relationship between these models, Specifically I cannot figure out how to define the Composite Key in the Journal Model to map to Account By CompanyId, AccountId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fluent APi (my personal preference - clear and less error prone):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Journal>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Account)
    .WithMany(e => e.Journals)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.AccountId, e.CompanyId });
```

But if you prefer data annotations, then apply the `ForeignKey` attribute on the *navigation property* and specify comma separated list of the FK properties:

```
public class Journal
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountId,CompanyId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```